# In Fortran90, is it possible to use a module from a file with a main program?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I have inherited some legacy Fortran90 code that I do not want to edit. The file `main.f90` has a module with some subroutines I'd like to use in my own program, but also has a main program.  It looks like this:

```
module libmain
    implicit none
    contains
    subroutine dostuff
        print *,'m'
    end subroutine dostuff
end module libmain

program main
    use libmain
    implicit none
    call dostuff
end program main
```

I want to use the module `libmain` in my own program in a file `myprogram.f90`, like this:

```
program myprogram
    use libmain
    implicit none
    call dostuff
end program myprogram
```

I've tried everything I can think of to make this work.  For instance:

```
>gfortran -c main.f90
>gfortran -c myprogram.f90
>gfortran -o myprogram main.o myprogram.o
```

This fails with the error:

```
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    main.o
    myprogram.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried leaving `main.o` out of the arguments to the final linking, but that also fails:

```
>gfortran -o myprogram myprogram.f90
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___libmain_MOD_dostuff", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in myprogram.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Interestingly, if I delete the files `main.o` and `libmain.mod,` I get a different error:

```
>rm main.o
>rm libmain.mod
>gfortran -o myprogram myprogram.f90
myprogram.f90:2:8:

     use libmain
        1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file ‘libmain.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

So `gfortran` knows that it should be looking for the `libmain.mod` file even if I don't include anything about `main` in the arguments when I try to link `myprogram.`. So why then does gfortran not find the symbol `dostuff`?  It obviously knows where to find the file `libmain.mod`, that's not the problem.

Edit:  I tried a few more tricks, none of which worked.

I thought that perhaps the problem is that `gfortran` expects the `.o` and the `.mod` files to have the same name, so I renamed:

```
>mv main.o libmain.o
>gfortran -o myprogram myprogram.f90

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___libmain_MOD_dostuff", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ccmD6cx3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So this doesn't work either.  I also tried the other way, moving `libmain.mod` to `main.mod`:

```
>rm *.mod
>rm *.o
>gfortran -c main.f90
>gfortran -c myprogram.f90
>mv libmain.mod main.mod
>gfortran -o myprogram myprogram.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___libmain_MOD_dostuff", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in myprogram.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I do the renaming before I compile `myprogram.f90`:

```
>rm *.mod
>rm *.o
>gfortran -c main.f90
>mv libmain.mod main.mod
>gfortran -c myprogram.f90
myprogram.f90:2:8:

     use libmain
        1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file ‘libmain.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

So I changed the reference to `main` inside `myprogram.f90` also:

```
program myprogram
    use main
    implicit none
    call dostuff
end program myprogram
```

while leaving `main.f90` unchanged. Now I do the following steps (starting from scratch):

```
>rm *.mod
>rm *.o
>gfortran -c main.f90
>mv libmain.mod main.mod
>gfortran -c myprogram.f90 
>gfortran -o myprogram myprogram.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___libmain_MOD_dostuff", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in myprogram.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So that fixed the file reference error, but I still don't get the symbol I need.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and use tag [tag:fortran] for all Frotran questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your pain, man. Even though already posted answer is the best advice you can get, it doesn't solve your issue in case you are dealing with leagacy, really legacy, code.

Let's try to hack it a little bit. Let's say you have your legacy code (you might be in a situation where you don't even have access to sources).

```
! a.f90
module libmain
    implicit none
    contains
    subroutine dostuff
        print *,'m'
    end subroutine dostuff
end module libmain

program main
    use libmain
    implicit none
    call dostuff
end program main
```

And, let's say this is your brand new `_main`.

```
! b.f90
program myprogram
    use libmain
    implicit none
    print *,'Hello from b'
    call dostuff
end program myprogram
```

Now, let's fix your issue with these nasty `_main` symbols laying all around.

```
> gfortran-8.3.0 -c a.f90
> objcopy -W _main a.o  # Force symbol _main to be marked as a weak
> gfortran-8.3.0 -c b.f90
> gfortran-8.3.0 -o main a.o b.o
> ./main
 Hello from b
 m
```

And voilà!

**P.S.**

Note that this is a hack, you may encounter lots of side effects, especially in case your original code sets some global variables, does some initialisation, etc. So, be careful with this approach.

Comment: I just tried a slight variant of this that preserves the original main.o file by renaming the modified version, seems to work as well.  Just supply main2.o as the final argument to objcopy and then do the linking step with main2.o instead of main.o.

Answer (score 2):

You simply cannot have two programs. It is not allowed in Fortran.

If you want to use the module, you can either copy it to a different separate source file, without the old program, or comment out the old program in the existing file.

You cannot link together two programs at the same time.

those tricks you tried are just red herrings, do not try to play with the .mod files or anything. Just somehow remove the old program from the compilation chain.